# How does Java's Dynamic Proxy actually work?

Tags: java, proxy

I understand how to use Dynamic Proxies in Java but what I don't understand is how the VM actually creates a dynamic proxy.  Does it generate bytecode and load it?  Or something else?  Thanks.

Comment: James, you're like a Java guru. Were you just testing us with this question?

Comment: Haha.  I know the Java language but I'm not a real VM expert.  :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At least for Sun's implementation, if you look at the source code of `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` you'll see that yes, it generates the byte code on-the-fly (using the class `sun.misc.ProxyGenerator`).

Answer (score 5):

I suggest that you read [Dynamic Proxy Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html):

> The Proxy.getProxyClass method returns
>   the java.lang.Class object for a proxy
>   class given a class loader and an
>   array of interfaces. The proxy class
>   will be defined in the specified class
>   loader and will implement all of the
>   supplied interfaces. If a proxy class
>   for the same permutation of interfaces
>   has already been defined in the class
>   loader, then the existing proxy class
>   will be returned; ***otherwise, a proxy
>   class for those interfaces will be
>   generated dynamically and defined in
>   the class loader.*** [emphasis mine]

Answer (score 2):

The proxy class is generated **on-the fly**(hence dynamic proxy)  and **loaded by** the classloader. That's why if you debug applications that relies on JDK proxying you'll see bunch of classes named '**com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0**'.

To test my theory you can use an example from [Dynamic proxy classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html)  along with the VM parameter  **-verbose:class** which will tell you the loaded classes by the classloader and you shall notice among the classes loaded the **com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0**.